# Blender Time Remapping "Bug"?

Tags: animation, materials

I have a plane with an animated gradient. I had to use time remapping because the animation is quite long and complex. When I Render it out with cycles it skips part of the gradient animation and it begins to stutter.

Instead of a movement every frame in which the gradient progresses, which in the viewport works fine, it goes Frame with movement, 3 frames without movement, frame with movement and so on.

When I switch to EEVEE everything works as it should. Unfortunately EEVEE in this case is only an option for preview.

Comment: Hi and welcome :) Please add as an [edit] some images of the scene, render settings, materials, etc [Gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963/what-is-the-process-for-creating-gifs-for-questions-and-answers) are also helpful if they show the problem clearly. Thanks :)

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply an the advice for future posts. Fortunatley I found a workarroung. It seems as if some texture properties don't work well when using time remapping. So instead of animating the gradient I animated the position which worked great.